# Synchronize School Data Sync (Classic) and Teams Groups - Owner and Members

Tags: synchronization, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to find a way, using my classic SDS synchronization, to designate a user as an owner without them being automatically added as a member of the group. I've seen that this is possible with the new version, but I'm looking to do it with the classic SDS.

Does anyone know a solution for this case? Thanks in advance.